# Node equivalent of ExpectedConditions.or for waiting for one of many elements

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using the Java driver, I can wait for one of several element conditions before taking an action, like so:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("idNumber1")),
    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("idNumber2"))
));
```

For instance, our `wait` will be over when just one of those elements listed are clickable.

However, I cannot find a way to do this using the Node.js version of the driver.

Comment: Have you tried `By.xpath("//*[@id='idNumber1' or @id='idNumber2']")`?

Comment: On second thought, the expected condition expects a single element, not an array, which is potentially possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, although there is no convenience method available in the Node version of the Selenium driver, I was able to emulate `ExpectedConditions.or` by using [Promise.any](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any).

```js
let item1 = By.id("idNumber1");
let item2 = By.id("idNumber2");
let result = await Promise.any(
   [ driver.wait(until.elementLocated(item1, 5000)), 
     driver.wait(until.elementLocated(item2, 5000))
   ]).then((el) => {
     if (el.getId() === 'idNumber1') {
       return //something specific to item 1;
     } else {
       return //something specific to item 2;
     }
   }
);

console.log(result);
```

Similarly, to emulate `and` you could use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).