# Checking the disappearance an element with selenium-webdriver and jest

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jestjs

Can't figure out how to check it the element has disappeared from the DOM.

```
  it('closes the modal on the close button click', async () => {
    await driver.get('http://localhost:3000/')
    const btn = await getElementXpath(driver, "//button[@class='Navbar__button']")
    await btn.click()

    const closeBtn = await getElementXpath(driver, "//button[@class='Modal__close']")
    await closeBtn.click()
    const modal = await getElementXpath(driver, '//div[@class="Modal__content"]')

    // here I need to check if the element is present
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EC (Expected Conditions) in Selenium, click [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to see the docs.

The expected_conditions module contains a set of predefined conditions such as `visibility_of_element_located` and `invisibility_of_element_located` which might be useful in this case.

Comment: There are no EC in Node

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523966/node-equivalent-of-expectedconditions-or-for-waiting-for-one-of-many-elements) on stackoverflow. Hope you might find it useful.